# How can I do to show a div of an element which is "automat" selected?

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

How can I do to show a div of an element which is "automat" selected?

If you look at this exemple : http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/2ehdW/ before make any click one part is selected (in yellow). I want to show a div and not only the yellow part.

So when the pie is "open" i want to show the div of the part pre-selected.

```
click: function (event) {
    if (!event.point.selected) {
        $('#testDiv').show();
        var chart_data = 'Name: ' + event.point.name + ' Share: ' + event.point.y;
        $('#testDiv').html(chart_data);
    } else {
        $('#testDiv').hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well it looks like it should be http://jsfiddle.net/2ehdW/4/ show/hide inverted option in click event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution could be to set the text of the div when you make it. Assuming you are dynamically making the chart you can dynamically set this as well.

```
<div id="testDiv"  style="height: 400px;">Name: Chrome Share: 12.8 </div>
```

And then remove your CSS display option so you see the div right away.

```
#testDiv {
//display: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2ehdW/6/

Might be a better solution out there if other people have anymore ideas.